# Round iPod connector

Tags: ipod-touch, audio

My car stereo claims to support my iPod touch, and has an iPod connector that is round. The car is second-hand, and no cable was supplied. It *isn't* the specific adapter shown below - nor indeed that specific ipod, but it is the same connector - and simply, I don't recognise it.

Searching for "round ipod cable" hasn't been fruitful. is this a common/known connector type?

[image: Stereo adapter]

Answer (score 4):

My first thought on seeing that was that it looks like a 9 pin DIN connector. So I did a quick Google and it looks like there are such things as 9 pin DIN to iPod leads. [This lead](http://www.dvbcaraudio.co.uk/dension-ipo4dc9-9pin-dock-cable-ipod-p-9564.html) for example looks to match (though the picture quality is rubbish so it's hard to tell).

Comment: Specifically, that's a mini-DIN connector.